# In WPF is there a way to change the position of a tooltip?

Tags: wpf, position, tooltip

I just want the tooltip to appear above the control instead of below. What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this attribute to your control: `ToolTipService.Placement="Top"`

Comment: Perfect! I was sure there was a simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If you want more info take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752368.aspx